# TypeScript module omitted when only used as an alias

Tags: module, typescript, react-router

I have an import statement of a NPM module like this:

```
import * as ReactRouter from 'react-router'
```

Which transpiles using `module: "commonjs"` to:

```
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
```

And I have access to `ReactRouter.Router`, etc. in my JSX. For example, this works:

```
render(){
    return (
        <ReactRouter.Router>
            <ReactRouter.Route path="/" component={App}>
                <ReactRouter.IndexRoute component={Index} />
                <ReactRouter.Route path="detail/:id" component={Detail} />
                {/* etc */}
            </ReactRouter.Route>
        </ReactRouter.Router>
    )
}
```

However, I want to create aliases to `Route`, etc. so I don't have to refer `ReactRouter.*` everywhere:

```
import * as ReactRouter from 'react-router'
import Router = ReactRouter.Router
import Route = ReactRouter.Route
import IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute

render(){
    return (
        <Router>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <IndexRoute component={Index} />
                <Route path="detail/:id" component={Detail} />
                {/* etc */}
            </Route>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

But when I do this, the transpiled code becomes this:

```
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;
```

Notice the `ReactRouter` module itself is nowhere, and at runtime it breaks because `ReactRouter` is undefined. However, if I stick at least one arbitrary reference to `ReactRouter` it shows up:

```
// TS
import * as ReactRouter
import Router = ReactRouter.Router
ReactRouter // reference to force ReactRouter module to be compiled

// Transpiles to:
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
ReactRouter;
```

And then it works at runtime.

So in other words, it seems that an import alias does not count as a reference, even though it really is. Is this a TSC bug? Is there a workaround other than creating an extra reference to the module so that TSC doesn't omit it? Is there a better way to import these individual symbols from the `react-router` module, like `import {Router, Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router'` can be done with Babel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [compiler bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4675). It was [fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/5046) a little while ago and you can either `npm install typescript@next` or use TypeScript 1.7 once it becomes available.

Referencing `ReactRouter` in an expression is the best workaround.

Comment: Nice. Fixed by you, it seems. :) Thanks!!

Comment: I guess there was no reason to use the passive voice there :)